# Script in Opencart

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

I hope you can help me with the following, I have tried many ways but I have not succeeded.

Basically my need is for the var product_mpn = ""; of the script to automatically read each "product-model" of each product that is entered of Opencart

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#DescriptionSectionOfYourPage").prepend("<div id=\"flix-inpage\"></div>");
jQuery("#AbovethefoldOfYourPage").prepend("<div id=\"flix-minisite\"></div>");
var product_mpn = "MODEL PRODUCT OF OPENCART";
var product_ean = "Dynamically add your product EAN";
var product_brand = "Dynamically add brand name";
var distributor = "xx";
var language = "xx";
var fallback_language = "xx";
var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
var flixScript = document.createElement('script');
flixScript.type = 'text/javascript';
flixScript.async = true;
flixScript.setAttribute('data-flix-distributor', distributor);
flixScript.setAttribute('data-flix-language', language);
flixScript.setAttribute('data-flix-fallback-language', fallback_language);
flixScript.setAttribute('data-flix-brand', product_brand);
flixScript.setAttribute('data-flix-ean', product_ean);
flixScript.setAttribute('data-flix-mpn', product_mpn);
flixScript.setAttribute('data-flix-inpage', 'flix-inpage');
flixScript.setAttribute('data-flix-button', 'flix-minisite');
flixScript.setAttribute('data-flix-price', '');
headID.appendChild(flixScript);
flixScript.src = '//media.flixfacts.com/js/loader.js';
</script>
```

I have trying with

```
var product_mpn = <?php echo $model; ?>;
```

but doesn't work

Comment: Which version of OpenCart you are use? Anyway if you need to get some value in template you need to declare it in corresponding controller file. In your case in controller file should be string like this: `$data['model'] = $model; // $model should be retrieved from DB`

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried this and other ways but they didn't work either unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

You could write it this way:

```
var product_mpn = "' + <?php echo $model; ?> + '";
```